How should I be sending transactions from my UI?
I want my website to be as performant as possible and for as many of my users' transactions to land as possible. What's a good way to do this?

This is the best logic I've been able to come up with. It re-sends transactions every 2 seconds, polling for updates every 200 ms. It also provides a callback so that you can use this in a toast. I err on the side of paying too much in priority fees, instead of waiting too long, but you can change this.
import { WalletContextState } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import {
  Transaction,
  Connection,
  SignatureStatus,
  ComputeBudgetProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
// Taken from:
// https://github.com/rpcpool/solana-prioritization-fees-api/
import {
  getMedianPrioritizationFeeByPercentile,
  PriotitizationFeeLevels,
} from "./grpf";
import { backOff } from "exponential-backoff";

// A minute of retries, with 2 seconds between retries and 200ms between status checks
const SEND_RETRY_INTERVAL_MS = 2_000;
const STATUS_POLL_INTERVAL_MS = 200;
const MAX_WAIT_MS = 60_000;

// 10k CUs is 0.03 cents, assuming 150k CUs and $250 SOL
const MIN_CU_PRICE = 10_000;
// 10M CUs is $0.38, assuming 150k CUs and $250 SOL
const MAX_CU_PRICE = 10_000_000;

type TxStatusUpdate =
  | { status: "created" }
  | { status: "signed" }
  | { status: "sent"; signature: string }
  | { status: "confirmed"; result: SignatureStatus };

// Sign and send a transaction with a priority fee. Assumes that the caller has already set the compute unit limit.
export async function signAndSendTransaction(
  connection: Connection,
  wallet: WalletContextState,
  txn: Transaction,
  onStatusUpdate?: (status: TxStatusUpdate) => void,
) {
  if (!wallet.publicKey) {
    throw new Error("Wallet not connected");
  }

  if (!wallet.signTransaction) {
    throw new Error("Wallet does not support signing transactions");
  }

  let medianPriorityFee;
  try {
    medianPriorityFee = await backOff(
      async () =>
        await getMedianPrioritizationFeeByPercentile(connection, {
          percentile: PriotitizationFeeLevels.HIGH,
        }),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Unable to get median priority fee");
  }

  const priorityFee = Math.min(
    Math.max(medianPriorityFee, MIN_CU_PRICE),
    MAX_CU_PRICE,
  );

  txn.add(
    ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
      microLamports: priorityFee,
    }),
  );

  let latestBlockhash;
  try {
    latestBlockhash = await backOff(
      async () => (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed")).blockhash,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Unable to get latest blockhash");
  }

  txn.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash;
  txn.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

  onStatusUpdate?.({ status: "created" });

  let signedTx;
  try {
    signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(txn);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("Wallet rejected transaction");
  }

  onStatusUpdate?.({ status: "signed" });

  let signature: string | null = null;
  let isComplete = false;

  const confirmationPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    // Status checking function
    const checkStatus = async () => {
      if (!signature) return;
      
      try {
        const response = await connection.getSignatureStatus(signature);
        if (response.value) {
          const status = response.value;
          if (
            status.confirmationStatus === "confirmed" ||
            status.confirmationStatus === "finalized"
          ) {
            onStatusUpdate?.({ status: "confirmed", result: status });
            clearInterval(statusInterval);
            clearInterval(sendInterval);
            isComplete = true;
            resolve();
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error checking status:", e);
      }
    };

    // Send transaction function
    const sendTx = async () => {
      if (isComplete) return;

      try {
        const isFirstSend = signature === null;
        signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(signedTx.serialize(), {
          skipPreflight: true,
          preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
          maxRetries: 0,
        });

        if (isFirstSend) {
          onStatusUpdate?.({ status: "sent", signature });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error sending transaction:", e);
      }
    };

    // Send transaction immediately
    sendTx();

    // Then set up the intervals
    const statusInterval = setInterval(checkStatus, STATUS_POLL_INTERVAL_MS);
    const sendInterval = setInterval(sendTx, SEND_RETRY_INTERVAL_MS);

    // Set timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(statusInterval);
      clearInterval(sendInterval);
      reject(new Error("Transaction confirmation timeout"));
    }, MAX_WAIT_MS);
  });

  await confirmationPromise;
}

